# Odoo13: mrp workorder

Tags: odoo-13

I want to get all components in work order Odoo basically get a product with tracking option only.

Is there an option or a way to get all component without filter or tracking option

Comment: Do you mean: filter components with the `product_tracking` field (which is related to `product_id.tracking`)?

Comment: Yes but now it's okay i'v figured out Thanks